# implementing List tail method in Scala

Tags: scala, linked-list, functional-programming

I am teaching myself Scala. In particular, I am following the book *Functional programming in Scala* by Chiusano et al. Chapter 3 presents you with an implementation of a linked list:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List{
  def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match{
  case Nil => 0
  case Cons(x, xs) => x + sum(xs)
  }

def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {
  case Nil => 1.0
  case Cons(0.0, _) => 0.0
  case Cons(x, xs) => x*product(xs)
  }      

def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] =
  if (as.isEmpty) Nil
  else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
}
```

and asks you to implement the function tail, that should return a list with all values but the first. I have implemented it in the following way:

```
def tail(ints: List[Int]): List[Int] = ints match {
  case Cons(x, xs) => xs
  }
```

(Partly, because I do not know how to implement the case in which the passed list is Nil).
However, when I have tested it on `List(1,2,3)`, the following is returned:

```
Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil))
```

instead of:

```
List(2, 3)
```

which is what I was expecting. Besides, I am using intellij, and the IDE won't let me write `List(1,2,3).tail`, but only `tail(List(1,2,3))`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Why is my tail implementation giving me such a strange return value? Why won't the IDE let me write `List(1,2,3).tail`? How to implement the case in which the list passed is Nil?

Comment: `Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil))` *is* the `[2; 3]` list (i.e. the `tail` of `[1; 2; 3]`, which is `Cons(1, Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil)))`). The string representation you see is default one for `case class`es. You could override it, like in the [stdlib](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L76). As for why you can't do `List(...).tail`, it's because your implementation is a function (that takes the list as a parameter), not a method on your class `List`.

Comment: `tail` of empty `List` throws an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why won't the IDE let me write `List(1,2,3).tail`?

What you've written is a stand-alone method that takes a `List` as a passed-in parameter. If what you want is to have a `List` return its own `tail` then you're actually half way there.

The `Cons` already has a `tail` member, you just have to promote it to the `List` definition and give the `Nil` a reasonable implementation.

```
sealed trait List[+A] {
  val tail: List[A]
}
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  lazy val tail =
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("tail of empty List")
}
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```